# Migrate an existing app in playstore from java to kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, migrate

this is more a theoretical question.

I have an app that is already in the playstore. This app has been working since the year 2017, so it has a lot of old libraries. The goal is to migrate it to kotlin. So, what's more effective to achive this goal:

1. Migrate file by file to kotlin
2. Create a new project with same buil.gradle in order to have the same id application. But at this point have another question, if I create a new app with the same id, package name.. can I generate a signed bundle apk with my old credentials?

I'm not pretty sure how to achive this goal. If there is a better I would really appreciate it you can teach me how.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The good point with Kotlin is that it can operate together with Java easily. To rewrite the app completely seems like a lot of work which would need an important reason. You can rewrite file by file and this way keep all functionality working.

If you keep the application Id in a new project, you can update your existing app only if you sign it with your old keystore. These are the two factors that identify your app.

Answer (score 4):

I recently converted an existing application to Kotlin.

Before you start, if you have not done so, I would recommend converting 
your application to AndroidX. It will save you a lot of headaches.

```
 **Android Studio Refactor/Migrate to AndroidX**
```

Note that during the conversion it will miss libraries and dependencies if you use
variables in your gradle file. When that is done and stable then go to Kotlin.

1: Add in the Kolin Libraries
    Project Gradle -

```
   classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.71"

Module Gradle ( **3 library choices - stdlib, jdk7, jdk8** ) 

  implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
```

2: Add the plugins to the Module Gradle

```
     apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
     apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

3: Converted the java files one by one using the automatic code conversion.
   Android Studio - Code/Convert Java class to Kotlin

Note that you will have breakage, mostly around parameter passing. You will need to 
   become conversant with ( !!, ? and let )

Another thing, as long as you have the Kotlin extension plugin you no longer need
   a library for dependency injection. You can pull out all of the Butterknife code.

I would NOT create a new application. I assume you are in bitbucket or github. Why
   hang on to the past. Convert and go on with your life.

Hope you find this useful.